Read Firebase data as soon as available Flutter
I have tried to implement a login system with riverpod and firebase in flutter.
This should be implemented in such a way that as soon as the login state of Firebase changes, all user data should be loaded automatically (from the db) and a listener should be initialized.
I implemented this by writing a stream provider that is responsible for parsing all data. However, I have a problem with this. In a special case it happens that the data does not yet exist at that time and I would like to write a loop that waits half a second in this case and then tries to load the document again, how can I implement this?
As far as I know, there is no way to initialize a listener to a db object that does not yet exist.
Here is my current code
basic Riverpod Provider for Firebase
final firebaseProvider = FutureProvider<FirebaseApp>((ref) async {
  return await Firebase.initializeApp();
});

final authStateProvider = StreamProvider<User?>((ref) {
  final firebaseApp = ref.watch(firebaseProvider).value;

  if (firebaseApp == null) {
    // Firebase is not initialized yet
    return const Stream.empty();
  }

  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(app: firebaseApp);

  return auth.authStateChanges();
});


The CurrentUser Provider
final currentUserProvider = StreamProvider<CurrentUser>((ref) {
  final authState = ref.watch(authStateProvider);

  //when the user is authenticated load data
  return authState.when(
    data: (user) {
      String uid = user!.uid;
      ref.read(inboxProvider).initInbox(uid);
      ref.read(recipeProvider).initRecipeListener(uid);
      // User is logged in, fetch user data from Firestore
      final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

      //this should be repeated if no data is available yet
      return firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).snapshots().map((snapshot) {
        final userData = snapshot.data();

        ... //Parse Data Here

        return currentUser;
      });
    },
    loading: () => const Stream.empty(),
    error: (_, __) => const Stream.empty(),
  );
});


"As far as I know, there is no way to initialize a listener to a db object that does not yet exist." I do and show exactly that in my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78827417/how-to-wait-for-a-firestore-document-to-be-created. Also see my longer explanation of it here: https://puf.io/posts/waiting-for-firestore-to-create-a-document. Also note that both of these link to a minimal example in zapp.run, so if you can't get it to work I recommend posting a similar repro.
